# How to return SAMSUNG GT-S5670 to Android 2.3.6 Gingerbread?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, 4.4-kitkat, recovery-mode, samsung

I have SAMSUNG GT-S5670, and I had android version Android 2.3.6 Gingerbread, but I wanted updated it to Android 4.4. Kitkat. I download on computer Cyanogen Mod and Google Apps package. I put it on SD card, got into recovery mode on mobile phone and then I made backup and after it I rebooted system. But it wont rebooted. It constantly turning on and on. What I can do, except that I need to bring it to a SASNSUNG service?! :( Help me somehow. Can I return it somehow to Android 2.3.6 Gingerbread again? :/

Comment: Welcome to  Android Enthusiasts! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please [edit] your question and include at least which CM packages you've used (and their download source). Are you sure you picked the right ones for your device? Have you wiped at least cache and Dalvik (otherwise instability or boot-loops are quite common)? Can you still boot into recovery?

Answer (score 0):

You can download matching firmware from [SamMobile.com](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/) and flash it through [odin](/questions/tagged/odin).

If you search XDA-developers you can find instructions on how you can flash an ODIN firmware. Some initial details can also be found in [our odin tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/odin/info).

Comment: Wouldn't that require the device to be booted in the first place? Sure, not in "operational mode" but "download mode" or the like. May I suggest to [edit] your answer and at least include  some links as well as describing the basic steps (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) and [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for details on "why")? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, sure! But I hadn't time to provide links :)

Comment: So take that as a reminder, and catch up :) As I've pointed out, you can [edit] your post anytime. Earn some rep, come on – I even help you get started – took me not more than 2 minutes to insert the links :) Your turn now!